# Moving to Xcode 7/Swift 2.0 causes app to get stuck on launch screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

Recently I moved to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 since my app wouldn't compile on iOS 9 (any device), however on iOS 8.x.x it ran as expected.

I have looked around Xcode and tried to find some reasons, but all I could find was that when it gets stuck on the launch screen, pressing pause in the Xcode debugger tells me that the code is on `objc_msgSend`. The CPU usage also hits 100% (use to only be ~10-20% on 8.x.x).

[image: CPU usage]

[image: Thread where app gets stuck on]

[image: objc_msgSend code]

Nothing else out of the ordinary. Everything worked fine on Xcode 6.4. I migrated all the code to swift 2.0 - I do not have any compiling errors - except `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'` but from what I've googled this isn't the biggest of my problems. I have no idea what to do anymore.

If you require parts of my code or whatever just let me know and I'll post it :)

Thanks!

**Edit**: Changed the storyboard to start at a regular `ViewController` and a label and it runs fine. Seems like it has something to do with me using a `UISplitViewController`. Here's some code from AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //get split VC
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    //Configure the master part
    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
    masterNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 236/255, green: 240/255, blue: 241/255, alpha: 1)
    masterNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 40/255, green: 162/255, blue: 47/255, alpha: 1)
    let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! NoteListViewController
    controller.context = self.managedObjectContext!


    //configure the detail
    let detailNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as! UINavigationController
    let detailViewController = detailNavController.topViewController as! NoteDetailViewController
    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    detailNavController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 40/255, green: 162/255, blue: 47/255, alpha: 1)



    //configure the data for detail
    controller.delegate = detailViewController
    let firstNote = fetchFirstResult(inContext: controller.context)
    if firstNote != nil{
        detailViewController.note = firstNote
        detailViewController.context = self.managedObjectContext!
        controller.tableIsEmpty = false
        controller.appHasLoadedOnce = false
    }




    return true
}
```

Comment: Go to > debug > Create breakpoint and choose exception breakpoint , run the app and let me know what your getting , you are right the warning your getting isn't supposed to give an expiation.

Comment: Still same thing. App gets stuck on the launch screen with no breakpoints stopping the app, but thanks for that I never knew that option existed ! Pausing it shows the same `objc_msgSend`

Comment: Try to clean your project, is it the first time you are running the project after converting to swift 2.0, its my pleasure ?

Comment: Cleaned several times. Have tried to change code also - it runs the `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)` I've tested that but once that it ran, nothing happens. As soon as I moved to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 I wasn't able to run my app.

Comment: there should be something, do you have code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?

Comment: @AaoIi edited my post, seems like it has to do with my `UISplitViewController`

Comment: is your app especially for iPad ? btw do you get any error printed in the console ?

Comment: it's universal. I created a new `UISplitViewController` and now it seems to correctly load - I will play around with it and let you know if I run into any other errors that seem odd. No errors in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you Storyboard.
Seems your screen contains TextField(s) with default text in it.
Simply clear text in this TextField and try again.

Comment: I have no clue how you noticed that... But I removed the words in the `UITextView` in the `detailViewController` and it works now? I'm so confused, yet ecstatic. Thank you so much

Comment: I've been breaking my head over this for hours, finally works because of this. Any idea why it doesn't work with default text?